# Check a dict key using assert from unit test

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to make an algorithm that checks if a key returns the same thing as the same key but with different values, like

I need to compare "success" with assert

I can't get to compare those 2 keys, I'm totally lost

```
return {'success': success, 'return message': return_msg, 'debug_data': debug_data}
return {"success": validation, "return message": return_msg, "debug_data": debug_data}
```

......

Comment: The comparison is based on the key `success`?

Comment: Yes, in one it returns success and the other validation

Comment: So, you want to compare if the values of `success`keys in the two dictionnaries are the same or not ?

Comment: that`s what I want, but I need to do with assert method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d1 = {'success': 'success', 'return message': 'return_msg', 'debug_data': 'debug_data'}
d2 =  {'success': 'validation', 'return message': 'return_msg', 'debug_data': 'debug_data'}


assert d1['success'] == d2['success']
```

If the values are not the same, you will get the exception `AssertionError`.

Comment: But like, I need to compare as it`s like there, they are not 2 separate dictionaries, they are just the return, and I need to compare like assert ["success"] == success

Comment: but it can`t be compared that way

Comment: YOu want to compare the first dictionnary to the second. Or you want just to compare that a dictionnary has a specific value by using `assert`syntax ?

Comment: Second question: You will do the `assert` when your function will do the return ?

Comment: actually your Idea made my code work, I was lost cause I never did an unit test before

Comment: for k in debug_data:
            assert k["success"] == RC.success
those 2 lines saved me

Comment: Ok. You're welcome. Next time take time to show the code. Without the code, we can not help you... Happy to know that my code helps you.